# Selected image of UITabBarItem does not fit the size of tab Swift iOS8+

Tags: swift, ios8, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I am trying to implement an `UITabBarController` with 2 `UITabBarItems` . I added in storyboard the TabBarController. I have on important issue with 
`selectedImage` property of `UITabBarItem` class.

The width of `selectedImage` does not fit the tab. I changed between devices, and for every device the selected image is over the other tab, or does not fit the current tab. (I found a solution: to have the same image but with different width for every device. But for sure this is not a good solution)

The selected image is that one with orange line in the buttom.

[image]
[image]

Any idea ?
Many thanks.

**EDIT - Code updated**
Here is the code which I implemented so far in `class MMHomeVC: UITabBarController`:

```
if let arrTabBarItems = tabBar.items {
        var tabBarItem1 = arrTabBarItems[0] as! UITabBarItem
        var tabBarItem2 = arrTabBarItems[1] as! UITabBarItem

        let imgHome         = UIImage(named: "btnHome")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
        let imgProfile      = UIImage(named: "btnProfile")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
        let imgSelectedTab  = UIImage(named: "selectedTab_imgBackground")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
        let imgHomeTabSelected  = UIImage(named: "tabHome_selected")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
        let imgProfileTabSelected  = UIImage(named: "tabProfile_selected")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)

        tabBarItem1.image = imgHome
        tabBarItem1.selectedImage = imgHomeTabSelected

        tabBarItem2.image = imgProfile
        tabBarItem2.selectedImage = imgProfileTabSelected
}
```

I played with `AlwaysOriginal`  and  `Automatic`  but no success.

Comment: Did you try this. UIImage("image name").imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.Automatic)

Comment: @Amit89 I tried with that also and no success!